# Ввод массива с консоли в Haskell

Tags: массивы, консоль, ввод, haskell

Мне надо ввести размер массива в консоль, а потом заполнить его элементами.

Например я вожу:

---

5

---

1 2 3 4 5

---

Вот например я ввожу размер

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    n1 <- readLn
```

И вот здесь уже я не нашёл как вводить элементы, такая функция как `getLine` вводит строку, а не целые числа

Comment: Вам нужно эту строку разбить по пробелам на список, а потом уже применить `read :: String -> Int` к каждому элементу. В результате получите список целых чисел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы разбить строку на слова, разделённые пробелами, используйте функцию [`words`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.9/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:words), затем каждое слово можно преобразовать в число с помощью функции [`read`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.9/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:read):

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    numbers <- map read . words <$> readLn
```

Учтите, однако, что функция `read` - это *частичная* функция. Это означает, что если какая-то часть входной строки не является числом, то ваша программа завершится аварийно. Если ваш вопрос связан с домашней работой или одноразовым скриптом, то это ничего страшного. Однако если вы пишете что-то долгосрочное, я бы рекомендовал воспользоваться более безопасными аналогами, такими как [`readMaybe`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.9/base-4.11.1.0/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe).

Также обратите внимание, что функции `read` нужно знать выходной тип. В вашем случае этим типом, по всей видимости, должен быть `Int`. Но этот тип нигде не указан. Если список `numbers` будет впоследствии передан в другую функцию, тип которой указан, то компилятор возьмёт тип оттуда, например:

```
printNums :: [Int] -> IO ()
printNums = print

main :: IO()
main = do
    numbers <- map read . words <$> readLn
    printNums numbers
```

Однако если вы попытаетесь вызвать функцию `print` без указания типа, то ваша программа не скомпилируется:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    numbers <- map read . words <$> readLn
    print numbers   -- ERROR: ambiguous type
```

Comment: Только тут массивы не используются, как написал автор. Можно ввести список другого размера, чем введено с консоли.